# Where is RoR defining objects it creates when you run rails generate scaffold without a database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to build a Ruby On Rails application that will allow the monitoring and controller of several Web Services.  I currently have those services operating and am able to see the 'status' of each service in a console application that lists the service and its status, viz.

```
Service1 Running
Service2 Paused
Service3 Waiting on Files
```

I want the RoR application to collect those responses into a collection of PORO objects called Process and the collection Processes, I think.  Then I would expect the default route to open the view 'process_list.html.erb' where a jQuery page would be used on load to create a DataTable 'process_table' that would be filled from that collection of Processes.  My problem is that, while I like the structure of RoR applications, I do not understand the flow of control in a RoR application.  If I were writing this in jQuery and javascript pages, I would know that my index.jsp page would include the jQuery DataTable javascript link which would be executed on loading the page.  That would reference another javascript function that would call the Web Service, collect the responses, convert that into a JSON array and return it to the DataTable, where it would be rendered as a table.  I could have a timer to periodically refresh the page, etc.  While it would work, and I have built such before, it seems like it would be much less 'organized' than a proper RoR application.

Here are the steps I've taken so far to where I am stuck:

1)    rails new maestro -O

2)    cd maestro

3)    rails generate scaffold processes show

4)    In routes.rb I added:

```
  resources :processes, :only => [:show]
  root 'processes#show'
```

This is supposed to take me to the apps/views/processes/show.html.erb page where I thought I could somehow provide a javascript page that would be executed on load to create the PORO objects and return them to DataTables as an array which could be handled via a foreach loop extracting the process.name, process.status into the table.  However, I get an error that in the app/controllers/process_controller.rb there is a section:

```
def set_process
  @process = Process.find(params[:id])
end
```

and 'find' is not defined for Process.  Now, I can't find a class 'Process' anywhere, and have no idea what this is or why it is being called.  There is a reference in an index method to @process = Process.all.  Again, where do I define these?

Are the steps I showed above the correct way to start building such an application and if so what do I do to create or edit the Process class and add those methods?  Where do I put the javascript for this page?  A few pointers to where to look, what to read so that I can understand the flow of a RoR application would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: Ruby doesn't really have any "plain-old Ruby objects" as Java might. In Ruby we just call those classes.

Comment: If you're using a current version of Rails you'll have access to [ActionCable](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) which can make real-time refreshing a lot less messy.

Comment: Did you generate the `process` model? If not, `rails g model process` to fill in the gap.

Comment: I'll look into ActionCable.  I tried the rails g model process and it printed out:
Running via Spring preloader in process 46121
but nothing seemed to change.  Same error undefined method 'all' for Process:Module.

Comment: @JohnWooten you should avoid naming your custom classes/modules with names of ruby's core classes/modules. E.g. there is already [Process](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Process.html) module in ruby's core. Otherwise this could lead to unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails scaffold makes a lot of assumptions expecting a convention for your controller action to correspond to a database model/table.  As others have mentioned, you should avoid using `Process` as it is a core ruby module, instead I'd suggest `MonitorProcess`.

If you want to use a database model to store things about process, then you'll need a model ( `rails g model monitor_process`)  and also for your controller use

```
rails generate scaffold monitor_processes
```

This however will build the standard MVC setup with , a migration to create the database table, a model class `MonitorProcess`,  a controller with RESTful routes ( index, show, new, create, update and destroy ), and views for index, show, new, edit, and a form partial used for new and edit, plus files setup for writing your tests.

If you don't need to access the database model, you can remove these from your controller, or comment them out.  But here's were you're off the path of MVC.

```
before_action :set_monitor_process, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def set_process
  @mocel_process = ModelProcess.find(params[:id])
end
```

From here you can consider using action cable and use your custom js on that page however you want.  But do you even need rails for this app??  It sounds like it might be more overhead than you need.  Scaffold is a tool which makes rapid prototyping of basic data driven app pretty fast and easy.  But it comes with a lot of conventions you probably don't need for your use case.

However, without knowing exactly what web services you want to create/monitor, and how,  It's hard to say whether you should or should not use Rails.  It's certainly able to be built to do many things outside of what Scaffold sets up for you.  That's just here for quick basic setup and avoiding a lot of boilerplate.   There's lots of frameworks to do things like background jobs etc.  But the question is, do you need MVC?  If not then you surely have other options.  If you need a backend only with decoupled front-end, you might have a look at [Using Rails for API-only Applications](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api)
If you like working with Ruby, [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com) might be another choice to [look into](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra).

Comment: That’s the impression I’m getting, RoR is overkill as it’s directed towards database use. I think I’ll resort to my old JavaScript approach as I know I can use web services from there.

Comment: Rails is out of the box, and MVC architecture, so unless you understand and need this pattern, you might wanna consider  alternatives.  See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again.  I usually try to use an MVC architecture as I like the separation.  I was trying to use RoR as it 'formalized' that, provided templates, authentication, and created very nice database based web sites.  Could you expand on your 'heres where your off the path of MVC' please.  Do you mean I should do the rails generate, then in the monitor_process controller make the changes you suggest?  What do they do?

Comment: I suggest spending time at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/ which do a better job of explaining then I am. The `before_action` will get called on restful routes `only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]` in this case.  If no params are passed in the `show` action for example, you will get the error.